# Installing tensorflow with GPU support

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu

I was trying to install tensorflow with GPU support using the instructions as given on:

1. [TenserFlow offical](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)
2. [Nvidia's installation Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4dqcd99IV)

But it seems that the installation is broken. I get the following error message when trying to import tensorflow:[image]

My head hurts now after trying over so many times and waiting for TF to install correctly. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: There is already an answer here -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159194/tensorflow-libcudart-so-7-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Also is there a script that can be run for the complete installation? (including NVIDIA drivers, CuDNN, Tensorflow)

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak Tried that.. doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a clean reinstall, This time with CUDA 8.0 and suppressed the OpenGL installation. This seems to work.